# math.max() doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to make a chart in my project. It is working fine except for the fact that Internet explorer isnt showing the chart. I found out that this is caused by the following code:

```
 max: Math.max(...data.datasets[0].data) + 15,
```

Does anybody know if there is a similar solution or any other way?

For the entire code and how it works see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4otw7vzu/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Math.max()` works fine in IE. The spread operator you're using doesn't work in IE. You will have to create the array in some other fashion.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `apply` instead of the spread operator:

```
max: Math.max.apply(this, data.datasets[0].data) + 15,
```

This works on IE: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4otw7vzu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of flowing for IE-11:

```
Math.max.apply(this, array)
Math.max.apply(window, array)
Math.max.apply(null, array)
Math.max.apply(array, array)
```

help URL: [Replit](https://repl.it/@artbindu/PolishedVisibleDecimal#main.js)